# Need the first 10 multiples of any number in Clojure

Tags: clojure

We've been given a task to print the first ten multiples of any number for which we have written the below code. It is throwing an error. In simple words, if n is 2 then we need to create a table of 2's till 10.

```
(defn multiples [n]
       (while ( n < 11)    
          (println( n * n))       
     (swap! n inc)))
(def n (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))
(multiples n)
```

With this, we're getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what **iterate** function does [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate)

```clj
(defn multiples-of [n]
  (iterate (partial * n) n))

(def ten-multiples-of-ten
  (take 10 (multiples-of 10)))
```

EDIT: I misread the author of the question, I believe he wants to just generate a sequence of squares. Here is one way using transducers, cause why not ;)

```clj
(def xf
  (comp
    (map inc)
    (map #(* % %))))


(defn first-n-squares [n]
  (into [] xf (take n (range))))
```

Comment: That is cool! :) - but it gives first an error. And I think OA wanted (1 .. 11) * n

Comment: in this case I think it is easier to use `range`.

Comment: Where is the error? Oh, I see, OP just wants a seq of sqares. Then a simple map like @Gwang-JinKim suggests would do.

Comment: `iterate` with `take` is an interesting construction, but since here, the increase is just by `inc`, a simple `range` would do it. But in other cases, `iterate` might give more interesting solutions, especially the increase would be dependent on the previous value of each step ...

Comment: I've updated my answer with even more complicated solution, lol ;) In general, (map (* % %) (range 1 n)) is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn multiples [n]
  (map #(* n %) (range 1 (+ 10 1))))

user=> (multiples 1)
;; => (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
user=> (multiples 2) 
;; => (2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20)
```

The resulting list you can loop over and `println` each of the elements.

```
(for [i (multiples 2)]
  (println i))

;; or:
(map println (multiples 2)) ;; though one usually doesn't apply 
                            ;; `map` on side effect functions ...
```

To improve your own construct:

You, coming from an imperative language, try to work with mutations.
That is very un-idiomatic clojure.
However, by declaring a value atom, you can access using the `@` operator to its place. And mutate the variable's value.

```
(defn multiples [n]
  (let [i (atom 1)]      ;; i is an atom
    (while (< @i  11)    ;; @i is the value saved into i
      (println (* @i n))
      (swap! i inc))))   ;; and correctly you can increase the value
```

With this multiples, you can also print the values.

You can't apply `swap!` to normal variables, only to atoms.

`while` loops one should apply only if number of elements not known.
In this case, one knows very well, when to stop. So use rather
a `for` loop.

```
(defn multiples [n]
  (for [i (range 1 11)]
    (println (* i n))))
```

Comment: how we can add println here

Comment: actually println is not very idiomatic - it is a side effect. But I will show you.

Comment: Input (stdin)
2
Your Output (stdout)
~ no output ~

Comment: in repl there is always output. You do usually in repl such stuff. But yeah use a `for` loop as I showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recur` in a loop:

```
(defn multiples [n]
  (if (< n 11)    
     (do  ; then
       (println (* n n))
       (recur (inc n)))
     nil))   ; else return nil
```

Running this by invoking

```
(multiples 1)
```

in a REPL will produce

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
nil
```